# I want to align "li" like an image while using [swiper-master] script

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to align "li" like an image while using [swiper-master] script!!

But I'm not used to using "display:flex" code..

so I don't know how to fix it.

How can I correct the alignment to be like the image??

I want to iterate over "li" like the image.

As shown in the picture, only li01 and li02 are arranged up and down, so I am satisfied!

The image has been attached with below!

※I didn't speak English, so I used a translator.

So the sentence may not be smooth. Sorry..!

[image]

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 4, 
    freeMode: true,
    mousewheel: true, 
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    transition-property: transform;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0)
    }

.swiper-slide {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition-property: transform
}

.swiper-container-3d {
    perspective: 1200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">li 8</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta change `.swiper-slide`'s `flex-direction` to `column` so that the elements inside of it could align vertical. After that i gave the elements inside `flex: 1` value in order them to spread within `.swiper-slide` and little bit of adjustment, Voilà.

[css flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Here is an example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 4, 
    freeMode: true,
    mousewheel: true, 
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    transition-property: transform;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}

.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-slide {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.swiper-container-3d {
    perspective: 1200px;
}

.inside {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <li class="inside">li 1</li>
      <li class="inside">li 2</li>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">li 8</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the flex related links:)